Characters associated to regular representation of SL(2,R)
Let $\pi$ be the regular representation of $G=SL(2,R)$ on $L^2(G)$. Let $M$ be the (commutative) convolution algebra consisting of finite Radon measures on $G$ that are bi-$K$-invariant where $K=SO(2)$. Define a homomorphism $\pi'$ from $M$ to the bounded operators on $L^2(G)$ by $\pi'(\mu)= \int \pi(g) d\mu(g)$. Then the image of $\pi'$ is a commutative *-algebra of operators on $L^2(G)$. What is the spectrum of this algebra? In other words, what are the nontrivial multiplicative linear functionals on $\pi'(M)$?
Each character pulls back via $\pi$ to a character on $M$, and the characters of $M$ are well-known. They correspond to irreducible representations of $G$ with K-fixed vectors. The spherical principal series appear in the decomposition of $\pi$ into irreducibles, but the complementary series do not.  Is it possible for a character associated to a complementary series repn to be the pull-back of character on $\pi'(M)$?
